# ImageResizer Out of Memory Exception on large image

Tags: c#, .net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I have inherited a site which is plagued with oversized and uncompressed images so I am automating the task of correcting it which is mostly working except for files over a certain size. For instance, I have a JPG image which is 8176x6132 300dpi and 24 bit depth, the file size is 4.49mb.

Here is my ImageJob

```
var instructions = new Instructions("width=1920;height=0;mode=max");
var resizedImg = new ImageJob(filePath, filePath, instructions).Build();
```

I have plenty of available resources on my machine yet get out of memory exceptions. As I test this right now I have 90% CPU free and 51% memory.

My machine has:

- Intel® CoreTMi7 Quad Core Processor i7-4790 (3.6GHz) 8MB Cache
- 16GB KINGSTON DUAL-DDR3 1600MHz

Why would this fail? As I run the ImageJob there is no increased usage of memory before it fails (as far as I can see).

I am using ImageResizer 3.4.3 with DiskCache plugin.

I should also note that I can open problem files in Photoshop, resize down to say 3000px along the long side, save and then run the same ImageJob which then completes without error.

[Diagnostics page output and exception stack trace](https://gist.github.com/ProNotion/e14d748a41ca8aeb00ee)

Comment: Why is the height `0`?  That could be the culprit.  So the first thing to look at, make sure you have sane input parameters going into the `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage` call.

Comment: Oops ImageResizer is a third-party lib, but it's open source, so you can step through the code to make sure it's passing sane values to `System.Drawing`.  Or, ask their support, which oddly enough points back to SO, how recursive.

Comment: I don't know what ImageResizer uses to do it's work, but if it's System.Drawing or WPF you might consider switching to something that uses ImageMagick. Because of the memory requirements of image resizing, I've found that spawning an Image Magic process can provide a certain level of isolation of your own process from the unbounded peril of arbitrarily large images.

Comment: The image requires a contiguous chunk of 150 megabytes of address space.  That can be hard to come by after the program has been running for while.  Be sure that the site runs in 64-bit mode so there's plenty of address space you can never run out of.  And be *very* sure to call the Dispose() method on the images, it is not going to last long when you don't.

Comment: @spender There are limits by default, he explicitly disabled them (see diagnostics). Diagnostics also show 32-bit process is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run the process in 64-bit mode instead of 32. It will have a better chance at locating the required 150mb, 62mb, and 12mb blocks  of contiguous memory that way. It's possible another 200mb might be required if you were triggering a fallback code path, or if the image was a CMYK jpeg (common) or had issues.

Second, since you're not using the URL API, make sure that you've limited the number of concurrent images you want to process. In ImageResizer v3, do them 1 or 2 at a time.

Third, upgrade to v4 and use the FastScaling plugin. [You'll get actual concurrency](http://imageresizing.net/blog/2015/v4highlights), and large blocks of RAM will be held for smaller amounts of time, meaning your throughput can easily go up 10x on files this large.

Comment: First of all thanks for the heads up about 64-Bit mode, I wasn't aware I had to explicitly change my Visual Studio setup to use 64-Bit on a 64-Bit machine, every day's a school day! WIth that change alone I can now process the remaining large images. Thanks